# how to generate a Http Request for AAD?

Tags: http, graph, request, azure-active-directory, scopes

so, I get the Access Token and I want to create a request...

`HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
                        AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesToken);`

`HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");`

Also, the Problem may be on setting the scopes for the authentication...i set it to:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
```

But I don't know if it gets all application permissions that I have (it is a deamon).

Comment: `try {
                IConfidentialClientApplication app;
                app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(additionals.ClientId)
                       .WithClientSecret(additionals.secret)
                       .WithAuthority(new Uri(additionals.uri))
                       .Build();
                result = Task.Run(async () => await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                                 .ExecuteAsync()).Result;
                }
    } catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex) {
}`

Comment: Do you want to list all users?

Comment: That scope will get you the permissions defined in your app registration. What issue are you having?

Comment: thanks for the reply...actually, I want to add events to users calendar without a user authentication...and that is possible if I authorize my application to do it...my problem is to create a URL that will do the POST request...i also create an Event Object before I start the request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph) which will help you to create events with same client credential flow which you are using but you need to change some things here.

You need to first give the Calendar.ReadWrite permission in the Azure portal for your app.

You need to add the below code in the Program.cs

```
if (result != null)
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var apiCaller = new ProtectedApiCallHelper(httpClient);
                await apiCaller.CallWebAPIToPostEvent($"{config.ApiUrl}v1.0/users/{user obj id}/calendars/{calendar id}/events", result.AccessToken, Display);
            }
```

Then you need to add the below classes in the protectedApiCallHelper.cs

```
public class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public Body Body;
    [JsonProperty("start")]
    public TimeAndDate Start;
    [JsonProperty("end")]
    public TimeAndDate End;
    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public Location Location;
    [JsonProperty("attendees")]
    public List<Attendees> Attendees;

}
public class Body
{
    [JsonProperty("contentType")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
public class TimeAndDate
{
    [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timeZone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
public class Attendees
{
    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public EmailAddress EmailAddress;
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type;
}
public class EmailAddress
{
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this same ProtectedApiCallHelper class you can create a post request and get the details by adding the below code

```
public async Task CallWebAPIToPostEvent(string webApiUrl, string accessToken, Action<JObject> processResult)
        {
            var defaultRequetHeaders = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
            if (defaultRequetHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequetHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
            {
                HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            }
            defaultRequetHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            var payload = new Event
            {
                Subject = "Let's go for lunch",
                Body = new Body
                {
                    ContentType = "HTML",
                    Content = "Does mid month work for you?"
                },
                Start = new TimeAndDate
                {
                    DateTime = "2019-03-15T12:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                End = new TimeAndDate
                {
                    DateTime = "2019-03-15T14:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                Location = new Location
                {
                    DisplayName = "Harry's Bar"
                },
                Attendees = new List<Attendees>
                {
                        new Attendees
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "Shiva@nishantsingh.live",
                                Name = "Shiva"
                            },
                            Type = "required"
                        }
                }
            };
            // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
            var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));

            // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(webApiUrl, httpContent);

            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
        }
```

This will help you create the event with these details.

Comment: thank you for your reply...I wrote what am I searching for as a reply to juunas

Comment: @AntonioJ let me research further on your requirement and get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: thank you...if you need more code from me, just write :)

Comment: May I ask you whether you have any news regarding my question? :)

Comment: @AntonioJ Sorry for being late, here is the code that helps you create the event.

Comment: @AntonioJ Thanks for the confirmation.Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions :)-